# NETLOGO: adding lists of agents' attributes to a list of lists

Tags: list, netlogo, nested-lists

Hello I am using Netlogo and I am trying to create a list of lists in which every sublist is a couple of agents' attributes. In particular I declare the list as a global variable and I initialize it to an empty list. Then I ask every agent to add a list of their attribute_1 and attribute_2 to the main list. Like this:

```
globals[mainlist]
set mainlist []
ask agents[
set mainlist sentence [mainlist] [attribute_1 attribute_2 ]
]
```

This should create a new list composed by the previous mainlist and the list [attribute_1 attribute_2].
Unfortunately this doesn't work and I get the error: EXPECTED LITERAL VALUE referring to "mainlist".
How should I write my code to create my list of lists in the correct way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `lput` or `fput` to add further elements to a list (`lput` will add the new list item at the end (l=last), whereas `fput` will add the new item at front (f=first)).
Additionally, you have to use the `(list ... ...)` primitive instead of `[ ]` brackets when you want to store variables in a list (brackets only work with constants).

Here is a working example:

```
globals[mainlist]

to test
  ask n-of 20 patches [sprout 1]
  set mainlist []
  ask turtles 
  [
    set mainlist lput (list xcor ycor) mainlist  
  ]
  print mainlist
end
```

Answer (score 5):

Tyr's answer is technically correct, but I would like to suggest a more netlogoish way to do it. Usually, in NetLogo, you don't have to build lists one element at a time. If you find yourself doing that, you might want to stop and try to approach the problem differently.

In this particular case, you can simply take advantage of the [`of`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#of) primitive:

```
[ (list attribute_1 attribute_2) ] of agents
```

Here is a fully working example:

```
breed [agents an-agent]
agents-own [attribute_1 attribute_2]
globals [mainlist]

to setup
  clear-all
  create-agents 10 [
    set attribute_1 random 10
    set attribute_2 random 10
  ]
  set mainlist [ (list attribute_1 attribute_2) ] of agents
  print mainlist
end
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Nicolas, your code is for sure functional, but for my specific application I need the agents to add their attributes to the list one at a time. Thank you anyway.